# Docker UCP API prune

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

In order to remove unused image, use the command

```
docker image prune [OPTIONS]
```

In particular, the parameter

```
--all , -a      Remove all unused images, not just dangling ones
```

[documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/)

How can I pass this parameter (--all) via Universal Control Plane API?
There aren't support such parameter

[documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/ucp/3.2/api/)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're looking at the `volume` API.

When you look at the `image` API, you'll see that there is a `dangling` parameter which is the equivalent of the `--all` on the command line.

[image]